# React Native Share result message is undefined in Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I use [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share) to implement share behavior.
I need to record which share options user click, sample code as below:

```
import Share from 'react-native-share';

Share.open(options)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.message);
  })
```

the ideal restult of `res.message` would be options item name, for example in iOS select copy is `com.apple.UIKit.activity.CopyToPasteboard`

but in Android I cannot any item name but just undefined in `res.message`

Does anyone ever use this library and know how to solve this problem in Android?
Or should I do any settings or modify AndroidManifest?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it print out any error messages when you add a .catch?

Comment: @caslawter No, there’s no error message:’( I thought maybe need some config in Android but has no idea